# Redirect one domain web request to other domain web request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a requirement to redirect web request to another url in rails.

Lets take my current app is xyz.com. If I hit the xyz.com/mno/dashboard, it has to redirect to abc.com/dashboard.

1. Reality we don't have mno controller in xyz.com.
2. when it hits routes it needs to send the request  to some controller(just consider like redirect controller)
3. In that redirection controller I want to handle my redirections to abc.com.

Answer (score 2):

You can just handle this in your `routes.rb` config:

```
get '/mno/dashboard', to: redirect('http://example.com/dashboard')
```

(Note - replace example.com with abc.com. StackOverflow wont allow any other domain if prefixed with http(s)://)

Comment: I would like to use one controller to take care the redirection. Is it possible to handle the redirections from controller instead of routes?

Comment: It would be slower, and pointless, to do the redirection in a controller. Just use routes - that's what they're for.

Comment: /mno/dashboard#xyz is redirecting to http://example.com/dashboard#xyz. But I don't want #xyz in http://example.com/dashboard. Is it possible?